# Preciso fazer uma conversao de dados de 2 tabelas diferentes

Tags: join, conversão

boa tarde a todos, eis me aqui novamente para fazer uma pergunta que para muitos é básico mas eu realmente não sei como fazer então bora lá.
tenho 2 tabelas originalmente em paradox, converti ambas para firebird para tentar facilitar o processo, no fdb tenho 2 tabelas, uma chamada clientes e outra ctareceber
na tabela 1(clientes) tenho os campos id, matricula, nome, endreço, etc...
na tabela 2(ctareceber) tenho matricula, valorpago, emissao, datapagamento, etc..
mas nao tem o nome do cliente, tem a sua matricula, o que eu preciso é
um select com os campos da tabela 2, porem, com o campo nome da tabela 1 no lugar da matricula da tabela 2, ex.

```
tab1
id matricula nome    endereco
1     1515   jose     rua das flores

tab2
id   matricula    emisao     vlrparcela   vencimento       pago
26    1515      30/01/2018      30,00        28/02/2019     0


eu preciso que fique assim:
tabx
id    matricula/nome    emissao   vlrparcela     vencimento     pago
26     jose           30/01/2019   30,00         28/02/2019      0
```

obs: coloquei matricula/nome porque para mim nao faz diferença o nome que ficar já que só irei usar para converter as contas dos clientes para outra base de dados

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT id,nome,emissao,vlrparcela,vencimento,pago
    FROM tab1
    JOIN tab2 ON tab1.matricula=tab2.matricula;
```

assim?

Comment: Vou tentar e ja retorno com o resultado

Comment: SELECT NOME,VENCIMENTO,EMISSAO,DATAPAGAMENTO,VALOR,VALORPAGO
FROM CTARECEBER
JOIN ctareceber ON CLIENTES.matricula=ctareceber.matricula;

Comment: SELECT NOME,VENCIMENTO,EMISSAO,DATAPAGAMENTO,VALOR,VALORPAGO
FROM CTARECEBER
JOIN ctareceber ON CLIENTES.matricula=ctareceber.matricula; deu erro   Column does not belong to referenced table.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -206.
Column unknown.
CLIENTES.MATRICULA.
At line 3, column 29

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde, consegui resover com a ajuda do Germano Buss Niehues, fiz um pequeno ajuste, deixarei aki como fiz para que possa ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

```
SELECT VENCIMENTO,CTARECEBER.ID,CTARECEBER.NUMERO,CTARECEBER.emissao,DATAPAGAMENTO,VALOR,VALORPAGO,clientes.NOME
FROM CTARECEBER
JOIN clientes ON ctareceber.matricula=clientes.matricula;
```